# add new row, to after datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

so, i have:
TextBox and Button

how i can add new value in datagrid?

for example
TextBox.Text = "sample text"

i click button, and DataGrid

`sample text`

input TextBox `sample text 2`

and click button, then

dataGrid:

`sample text`

`sample text 2`

etc...

please help!

Comment: 1. Bind to a list of strings. 2. Add to that list. 3. Done.

Comment: please make your question clear, your way of asking question is not good in terms of style

Comment: Based on the content of the question and formatting, I suppose you try to pass some exam at the moment, isn't right? The case is that you did not put any effort in constructing the question nor to resolve the problem by your own (which is trivial)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a datagrid, a textbox and a button on you window in xaml, in codebehind:

```
ObservableCollection<string> list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public Window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        datagrid1.ItemsSource = list;

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        list.Add(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

bind your itemssource of your datagrid to a observablecollection.
Then if you click on button just do something like that

myitemssource.add(new myitemtype());

in a very easy case:

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    ObservableCollection<Person> _persons;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return _persons ?? (_persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>()); }
        set { _persons = value; }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var split = txtBox.Text.Split(' ');
        try
        {
            Persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = split[0], LastName = split[1], Age = Int32.Parse(split[2]) });
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

<Window x:Class="ItemsControlTest.TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="TestWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Name="txtBox" Text="Firstname lastname 10"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click" Content="click me"/>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}">

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```